# Error: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to set the source of a certain element, it returns an error and I have no clue why this is not working.
Here is the javascript:

```
    function playVid() {
  var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("video");
  var mp4VID = document.getElementById("videoSRC");
  var arrOfVid = ["video/video.mp4","video/video1.mp4"]; //, "video/video2.mp4", "video/video3.mp4"];
  var arrLenVID = arrOfVid.length;
  var randomVID = Math.floor((Math.random() * arrLenVID));
  mp4VID.src = arrOfVid[randomVID]; // mp4VIDSRC.src = arrOfVid[randomVID]
  videoPlayer.load();
  videoPlayer.volume = 0;
  videoPlayer.play();
}
playVid();
```

The HTML part of it is:

```
<video id="video" autoplay="" style="" muted="">
<source id="videoSRC" src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    error: unsupported video format
</video>
```

Here's the error message I'm receiving:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Nothing else seems to cross paths with it.

Comment: `Cannot set property 'src' of null` means that you haven't successfully selected an element. You have probably included the script before the HTML.

Comment: Where is that JavaScript found? Present a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an HTML page is loaded, the browser attempts to execute things in the top of the page before the page is completely loaded. So if your javascript function call (`playVid();`) is at the top of the page, it is trying to execute `var mp4VID = document.getElementById("videoSRC");` before the videoSRC is loaded. Therefore mp4VID is null, and you can't set a property on a null object. You have two options if this is the case.

**1)** move the function call to the bottom of the page, just before the closing html tag.

**2)** Use a framework like jQuery and schedule the function call to execute after the page is loaded `$(document).ready(playVid);` for example.

*#2 is my preferred method:*

In my experience, most people don't like when videos start to automatically play.

Comment: Thanks have been digging at this for days!

Comment: @Ashwin if this is the answer you accepted, could you please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark by the vote up/down. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set it to a value because mp4VID is a child of video:
instead set `var mp4VID` to equal `videoPlyr.children["videoSRC"]`.

Hope this answered your question :)