# Cannot set property 'src' of null- Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension which should pick up url of the currently open tab.
The extension is popup based so I made an html the code of which is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>popup</title>    
</head>
<body>
<img src="www.insertrandom.com/query=" id="urlstore">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I open this webpage and inspect element (ctrl+shift+i), there are NO errors at all.
But if I inspect elements on other webpages(which are actually on internet) like, stackoverflow I get the error:

> Cannot set property 'src' of null

Previously asked questions on stackoverflow, like these:
[Cannot set property 'src' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237142/cannot-set-property-src-of-null) and
[Error: Cannot set property 'src' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958313/error-cannot-set-property-src-of-null) are unable to solve the issue.

```
//content.js
var curr_url = window.location.href;
var base_url = "www.insertrandom.com/query=";
document.getElementById("urlstore").src = base_url+curr_url;
```

And another problem is that when I open the popup on other web pages, the url that I get is `chrome-extension://insertrandomid/popup.html` and not the current url

Comment: 1) content.js is a misleading name as you're loading it as a normal script inside your popup page, not as a content script. See the [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). 2) The popup is a separate page with its own location.href so it's not what you want, instead [use chrome.tabs API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17826527) (note, it's asynchronous so use the result inside the callback). 3) URLs inside `src` attribute should start with `http://` or `https://` otherwise it'll be interpreted as a relative path.

Comment: Also, make sure you're using [the correct devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982) for the popup.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm 1) I'll change the name of the js file, it's my first extension so couldn't manage while copying-pasting 2) Sure, I'll use chrome tabs API but I don't understand the part you wrote: "it's asynchronous so use..." can you please explain? 3) URL is starting with https:// I changed the link while posting the question.

Comment: @wOxxOm I get the error `Cannot read property 'query' of undefined` when I use the code `chrome.tabs.query(active...)`.

Comment: It means you still don't know the difference between the popup page (and its scripts) and the content scripts. Did you read the overview I've linked?

Comment: I did read the page, From my understanding: Popup is the html page which comes down from extension when we click it. content.js contains the javascript that interacts with the webpage of the user. I also understood that script of popup can be different from content.js . I also wanted to update you that just to confirm that I'm replying you with right content, I re-read the page and I have got my answers. Thank you!

Comment: My point was the task at hand doesn't require a content script, only a popup script where you can use chrome.tabs API while content scripts can't use chrome.tabs and most of chrome API because they run in a special isolated environment alongside the web page.

Answer (score -2):

Notice that `document.getElementById("urlstore").src = base_url+curr_url;`.
That means you need an element with id `urlstore` on your page. If the element with id `urlstore` is not exist/include **src** attribute, you will get the error `Cannot set property 'src' of null`.
If `document.getElementById("urlstore")` exists, you should log this element to check whether **src** attribute exists: `console.log(document.getElementById("urlstore"));`

Comment: But if you look at the html code, I clearly have the <img> tag that has id ="urlstore"